# Extract information from std::string

Tags: c++, stdstring

Too many string related queries yet some doubt remains, for each string is different and each requirement is different too.

I have a single string in this form:
`Random1A:Random1B::String1 Random2A:Random2B::String2 ... RandomNA:RandomNB::StringN`

And I want to get back a single string in this form:
`String1 String2  ... StringN`

In short, the input string would look like `A:B::Val1 P:Q::Val2`, and o/p result string would look like "`Val1` `Val2`".

PS: `Randoms` and `Strings` are small (variable) length alphanumeric strings.

```
std::string GetCoreStr ( std::string inputStr, int & vSeqLen )
{
    std::string seqStr;
    std::string strNew;
    seqStr = inputStr;
    size_t firstFind = 0;
    while ( !seqStr.empty() )
    {
        firstFind = inputStr.find("::");
        size_t lastFind = (inputStr.find(" ") < inputStr.length())? inputStr.find(" ") : inputStr.length();
        strNew += inputStr.substr(firstFind+2, lastFind-firstFind-1);
        vSeqStr = inputStr.erase( 0, lastFind+1 );
    }
    vSeqLen = strNew.length();
    return strNew;
}
```

I want to get back a single string `String1` `String2` ... `StringN`.

My code works and I get result of my choice, but it is not an optimal form. I want help in improving the code quality.

### I ended up doing it the C-way.

```
std::string GetCoreStr ( const std::string & inputStr )
{
    std::string strNew;
    for ( int i = 0; i < inputStr.length(); ++i )
    {
        if ( inputStr[i] == ':' && inputStr[i + 1] == ':' )
        {
            i += 2;
            while ( ( inputStr[i] != ' ' && inputStr[i] != '\0' ) )
            {
                strNew += inputStr[i++];
            }
            if ( inputStr[i] == ' ' )
            { 
                strNew += ' ';
            }
        }
    }
return strNew;
}
```

Comment: *'My code works and I get result of my choice but it is not an optimal form. I want help in improving the code quality.'* – then this code is more appropriate for [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)...

Comment: What you still could improve: drop that copy of inputStr (`seqStr`), I do not see where you ever would need it. Then there's an overload of std::find providing an offset parameter. Instead of erasing the string more and more until empty, you could instead re-start next search just with the adjusted offset and leave the string as is (you could accept it as const reference then, too). You'd iterate over the string until the offset gets greater or equal to string's length.

Comment: You're calling `find` twice on assignment to lastFind. I'm not sure if the compiler can optimise that second call away – especially, as the input string is not const. Better: `lastFind = find(); if(lf > length) lf = length;`  or even: `lastFind = std::max(find(), length());`. Additionally: What happens, if the space occurs before the double colon? I'd restart searching for it only *after* `firstFind` (second overload as mentioned before).

Comment: I am having trouble deciding on how to adjust the offset. I am erasing the string already parsed just to overcome this issue. Also, there won't be any blank before the _double colon_.

Answer (score 2):

> I am having trouble deciding on how to adjust the offset. [...]

```
std::string getCoreString(std::string const& input)
{
    std::string result;
    // optional: avoid reallocations:
    result.reserve(input.length());
    // (we likely reserved too much – if you have some reliable hint how many
    // input parts we have, you might subtract appropriate number)

    size_t end = 0;
    do
    {
        size_t begin = input.find("::", end);
        // added check: double colon not found at all...
        if(begin == std::string::npos)
            break;
        // single character variant is more efficient, if you need to find just such one:
        end = std::min(input.find(' ', begin) + 1, input.length());
        result.append(input.begin() + begin + 2, input.begin() + end);
    }
    while(end < input.length());
    return result;
}
```

Side note: you do not need the additional 'length' output parameter; it's redundant, as the returned string contains the same value...